# Is there an intuitive explanation for the direction of the B field around a wire?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

A wire has cylindrical symmetry, therefore we should consider the possibility of the induced by field in the p,phi and z directions. I know from the right hand rule that we only get a field in the phi direction but I'm not sure how we show that there is no field radially or along the length of the wire.

Comment: Do you know the B field a point charge produces by definition? If not: http://maxwell.ucdavis.edu/~electro/magnetic_field/pointcharge.html

Comment: @SofiaV a stationary change doesn't but I'd guess some form of the biot savart law could by used to work out the field of a moving charge? Although ideally I'd rather not justify it with maths

Comment: A radial B field component would imply a finite magnetic monopole density.

Comment: @goods I think "not justifying it with maths" is not a good way to go here since this concept is so deeply ingrained in the theory. Although probably I lack knowledge here.

Comment: Note that the direction of the field's winding is largely a matter of convention. What we observe are the *forces* that arise. But we could get the forces by uniform application of right-hand-rules (what we do) or left-hand-rules (which would reverse the direction of the field, but yield the same predictions for the forces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that the closed surface integral of the magnetic flux is always zero, right?

One way of thinking about this, is that if you consider a closed surface (for example, a cylindrical surface enclosing the wire), then there must be as many magnetic field lines entering that surface as there are leaving the surface. In other words, the lack of magnetic monopoles means that magnetic field lines do not begin or end.

Given that, how could one arrange for that to be true for the cylindrical surface if field lines were looking radially outwards from the wire?

In terms of along the wire, well the same thing is true. No field into the cylinder on its flat faces and no field out. You could however hypothesise a constant field along the axis of the wire, but here we must appeal to the Biot-Savart law - the field must be perpendicular to the current.